# Accessing .au3 file from .au3 file

Tags: autoit

How can I access a .au3 file in "My Documents/Downloads" folder from another .au3 file?

I know how to access the file from the desktop from this code:

```
Run(@AutoItExe & ' "' & @ScriptDir & '\file2.au3"')
```

But I can't access it in "My Document/Downloads" folder. Basically I want to recursively call the same .au3 file again and again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as an alternative, the way to run a program in the folder you want is:

```
Run(@AutoItExe & ' "' & @MyDocumentsDir & '\Downloads\file2.au3"')
```

Furthermore, if you want a method like the other one then you could use #include inside the loop.

Comment: Sometimes Run doesn't work though. I can't remember when I had it the last time. Try ShellExecute if that happens.

Answer (score 5):

Calling an au3 file from in another au3 file seems to be a little redundant. Couldn't you just copy the code you need from the au3 file into your same file and then put it in a loop? For example, the following ode would run the code 10 times.

```
For $i = 1 to 10
    ;Code from file2.au3
    MsgBox(0,"", $i)
Next
MsgBox(0,"", "Done!")
```